# OCaml: Return string within an IF statement

Tags: string, ocaml

I would like take a string, and call different functions to get result according to some types of the string. My code looks like:

```
let convert_string lval value =
if (String.index value '{' > 0) then
   Pretty_utils.sfprintf "%s" convert_1 lval value
else 
   Pretty_utils.sfprintf "%s" convert_2 lval value
```

However, this code raises compiler error:

"This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type unit".

Anybody familiar with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `()` for `convert_1 lval value`

```
let convert_string lval value =
  if (String.index value '{' > 0) then
    Pretty_utils.sfprintf "%s" (convert_1 lval value)
  else 
    Pretty_utils.sfprintf "%s" (convert_2 lval value)
```

Answer (score 3):

The "%s" format only take one argument, and you gave it 3, You probably meant to use "%a %s" :
if convert_1 and convert_2 are the function meant to print lval.

```
let convert_string lval value =
   if (String.index value '{' > 0) then
      Pretty_utils.sfprintf "%a %s" convert_1 lval value
   else 
      Pretty_utils.sfprintf "%a %s" convert_2 lval value
```

Comment: Thanks all for the guide. It works now. However, it raises Not_found error at runtime. I used try .. with Not_found, then it works but it can only handle two cases. I want to handle more than 2 cases, e.g. 
     if .. then

     else if .. then 

     else   
what can I do?

Comment: If there is no '{' in your code there will be a Not_found. You just have to put the other case in the `with Not_found -> ....` exception handler (there you can use any ocaml code, even an if)

Comment: Note that you seem to do parsing of some string there, you probably better use more specialized tool for this, like ocamlyacc/ocamllex or regex or stream parser or camlp4 parser, but this is the subject of another question (probably already asked somewhere)

Answer (score 3):

You have to isolate the function (convert_x) and its arguments or ocaml will interpret all the values after sprintf as arguments to sprintf.

```
let convert_string lval value =
  if (String.index value '{' > 0) then
    Pretty_utils.sfprintf "%s" (convert_1 lval value)
  else 
    Pretty_utils.sfprintf "%s" (convert_2 lval value)
```